# Unable to Convert Linq to Lambda Notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
 public ActionResult EditArticle(int id)
    {
      if (id == null)
      {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }
      var typeId = 0;
      var catId = 0;
      var subCatId = 0;
      var viewModel = (from sa in ems.SupportArticles
                       join ssc in ems.SupportSubCategories on sa.SubCatID equals ssc.SubCatID
                       join sc in ems.SupportCategories on ssc.CatID equals sc.CatID
                       join st in ems.SupportTypes on sc.TypeID equals st.TypeID
                       where sa.ArcticleId == id
                       select new SupportArticleViewModel { supportArticle = sa, supportSubCat = ssc, supportCat = sc, supportType = st });
      foreach (var vm in viewModel)
      {
        typeId = vm.supportType.TypeID;
        catId = vm.supportCat.CatID;
        subCatId = vm.supportSubCat.SubCatID;
      }
```

I want to convert it into Lambda Notation.But, I am unable to do it.Please help.I am using SupportViewModel which contains property of SupportType,SupportCategory ,SupportSubCategoryand SupportArticle.

Comment: lamda means you wan to do like functions rather than query like this

Comment: Hi provided you ans try out at your end ...

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Comment: Yea.Running Like Butter. But, I want to convert Linq statement of Join to Lambda

Comment: this is join one what else you want .....what do you mean by linq statment of join to lambda ...lambada notation.......not getting what youare trying to achieve

Comment: are you trying expression tree ???

Comment: Give any example of Lambda Notation...............where you have seen this

Comment: I think he's trying to do that with method chaining, like: `someList.Where(item => item.Property.GetType() == typeof(int)).Select(item => (int)item.Property)`. But I don't know much about LINQ query, so I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is functional way do query , you have to make use of join function and than you get data

```
 var filteredArtciles = SupportArticles.Where(sa=> sa.ArcticleId == id);
 var query =
        SupportArticles.
         Join(SupportSubCategories,sa  =>  sa.SubCatID ,ssc => ssc.SubCatID,(sa, ssc) => new {sa,ssc}).
         Join(SupportCategories,sassc  =>  sassc.ssc.CatID ,sc=>sc.CatID ,(sassc, sc) => new {sassc,sc}).;
         Join(SupportTypes,sasscsc  => sasscsc.sc.TypeID  ,st=>st.TypeID ,(sc, st) => new {sasscsc,st}).
         Select(j=>
             new  SupportArticleViewModel 
               { 
                  supportArticle = j.sasscsc.sassc.sa, 
                  supportSubCat = j.sasscsc.sassc.ssc,
                  supportCat = j.sasscsc.sc,
                  supportType = j.st 
               }
        ));
```

Comment: Why do you add `ToList()` when the OP doesn't have it in his code? For certain scenarios, like reusing the same iterator multiple times where the query is expensive and the result set is small, this may be preferable. By doing `ToList()` you miss the benefits of lazy evaluation, and for a large dataset, this may create undue memory usage.

Comment: @AshleyPillay - removed tolist () .....as op not requested ...i know tolist() will run query immediately...but updated my answer

Comment: @SiddharthSinha - try now ...it very difficut with fuction and become unreadable ...its my suggestion you stay with query version

Comment: Thanks pranay. I got it now

Comment: Sorry,But it didnt. But Thanks.Ia m going with my LINQ part

Comment: @SiddharthSinha - ok but your post says i got it now, so it not wokred for you ???

Comment: No. Sorry.You said me to be with linq...So I said..Okay, I will do it LINQ. But thanks for the help. I will try to implement your join knowledge on forthcoming tasks.

Comment: @SiddharthSinha - i tried linq query in linqpad application, and tried to create query for you, it becomes very difficult to write query with this much join, suggest you have try and please od accept/upvote answer if it works